# how to add client confirmation on delete record in asp.net core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

i am use asp.net core 1.0 and in this i want to add client confirmation on delete record

**my code belowe**

```
@model IEnumerable<Login.Model.UserAccount>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Registered user</h2>
        @if (Model.Any())
        {
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>EmaiID</th>
                    <th>Use Name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
                        <td>@item.LastName</td>
                        <td>@item.Email</td>
                        <td>@item.UserName</td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.UserID">Edit</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.UserID">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <p> There is no registered users.</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

in above code delete operation perform successfully but i want to add add client confirmation before delete, if action ok than delete and if action cancle than not delete.

Comment: Sounds like you need javascript code here. Somethink like:

```$('#deleteLink').click(function(e)){
 if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete)){
  e.preventDefault();
 }
}```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ConfirmDelete()
{
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");

    return X;
}


<input type="button" Onclick="ConfirmDelete()">
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, what's the advantage of `if (x) return true; else return false;` over a simple `return x;`?